# track all external links on blog via username

Tags: plugins, links, username

I’ve been searching for a plugin that can track all external links clicked on a blog. Unfortunately the ones that I’ve found are intended to track total clicks per link rather than tracking which user clicked on which link. Is there a plugin that will enable me to track links based on the username?

If not, I can write a script to intercept each click, save the username to a db and then redirect to the correct page. But I need some way to determine username before the link is clicked. Is there a plugin that will enable me to insert a parameter (username) to any url/link in a blog post?

For example:
http://myblog.com/myscript.php?url=http%3A//www.google.com&user={{username}}

I’ve looked at the wordpress API and it seems easy enough to retrieve user account info but if I’m linking to a custom script (rather than a wordpress page) which wordpress files do I need to include so that I’ll have access to the WP_User object?

```
<?php
// include “someWordPressFile.php”;
$user = wp_get_current_user();
?>
```

Comment: Have jQuery intercept all clicks and to a send a get request to admin-ajax.php. There you can handle the DB update and track the user. Just ignore the _no_priv handler to only trigger for logged in users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of an existing plugin that does what you want.

Using a custom script is quite difficult, I would not try this. Mainly because you do not know which WP functions you can use/which functions need others to work, ...

If you want to track links then I would use an ajax event send a "click" event to WordPress when someone clicks on a link. Also you do not need to include the username in the URL, since you can always use `get_current_user_id()` to determine the logged in users ID.

The solution could be a simple script, with this structure:

```
// 1. Add a javascript for click-tracking on every WordPress page.
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_tracking_script' );
function add_tracking_script() {
    ?><script>jQuery(function(){
      function domain(url) {
        return url.replace('http://','').replace('https://','').split('/')[0];
      }

      var local_domain = domain('<?php echo site_url() ?>');

      jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
        var link_url = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        if (domain(link_url) === local_domain) {return true;}
        window.wp.ajax.send('tracking-click', {url: link_url})
        return true;
      })
    })</script><?php
}

// 2. Add the ajax handler for the tracking.
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tracking-click', 'ajax_handler_tracking' );
function ajax_handler_tracking() {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id();
  $url = $_REQUEST['url'];

  // Save the user_id + $url to your DB table...

  exit;
}
```

**Update**

If you get an JS error `window.wp.ajax.send is undefined` then you also need to add this php code to tell WordPress that you want to use `window.wp`

```
// 3. Make sure WordPress loads the window.wp object:
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_wp_utils' );
function add_wp_utils() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-utils' );
}
```

FYI: You can find a bit more information on `window.wp.ajax` in this post https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/245275/31140

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for. Made a couple of changes to the onclick code to skip the domain() function.

Comment: How do you have access to `window.wp.ajax.send` ? I keep getting undefined.

Comment: @jgraup This function is not always available. you need to add this to your functions.php code: `wp_enqueue_scripts( 'wp-utils' );` - this will add the javascript object `window.wp` to your website

Comment: @Philipp - that's pretty handy. Are there docs on this script?

Answer (score 1):

I realize someone basically made my comment and added as an answer. Here is a fully working version using the built in [REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/adding/) for variety. It was a little tricky finding docks on authenticated requests, but this should be a drop in.

```
// send authorization info
beforeSend: function(xhr) {

    // attach REST nonce for logged in user requests -- otherwise will end up no-priv
    xhr.setRequestHeader ('X-WP-Nonce', '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>');
},
```

On an click to an external link, an ajax call is made to a custom REST route. The link is then added to an array of urls in the users meta and incremented for count data.

After a few external clicks you can check the metadata for the user and see all the clicks and counts.

```
<?php

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {

    // namespace of url
    $namespace = 'v2';

    // route
    $base = '/link/count/';

    // register request
    register_rest_route( $namespace, $base, array (

            // hide from discovery
            'show_in_index' => false,

            // only accept POST methods
            'methods'       => 'POST',

            // handler
            'callback'      => 'add_link_count',

            // validate args
            'args' => array(
                'link' => array(
                    'validate_callback' => function($param, $request, $key) {
                        return ! empty( $param );
                    }
                ),
            ),

            // check for logged in users
            'permission_callback' => function () {
               return is_user_logged_in();
            }
    ) );
} );

// only add late in the footer
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {

    // only add for logged in users
    if ( ! get_current_user_id() ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($) {

            // only search for links with data
            $ ('a[href^="http"], a[href^="//"]').each (function() {

                // excluded specific domains
                var excludes = [
                    'example.com'
                ];
                for (i = 0; i < excludes.length; i++) {
                    if (this.href.indexOf (excludes[i]) != -1) {
                        return true; // continue each() with next link
                    }
                }

                // filter by domain -- only track external links
                if (this.href.indexOf (location.hostname) == -1) {

                    // attach click event
                    $ (this).click (function(e) {

                        // do ajax call
                        $.ajax ({

                            // send request to REST URL
                            url: '<?php echo esc_js( get_rest_url( null, '/v2/link/count/' ) ); ?>',

                            // use the accepted method - POST
                            method: 'POST',

                            // send authorization info
                            beforeSend: function(xhr) {

                                // attach REST nonce for logged in user requests -- otherwise will end up no-priv
                                xhr.setRequestHeader ('X-WP-Nonce', '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ); ?>');
                            },
                            data: {
                                // link to track click count
                                'link': this.href
                            }
                        }).done (function(response) {
                            // show response in the console
                            // console.log (response);
                        });

                        // block click -- for testing
                        // e.preventDefault();
                    });
                }
            })
        } (jQuery));

    </script>
    <?php
}, 30 );

// handle the REST url
function add_link_count( $request ) {

    // get the current user
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    // check for valid user id > 0
    if ( ! $user_id || $user_id < 1 ) {
        return new WP_REST_Response( 'Unauthorized', 403 );
    }

    // get the link to log
    $link = $request->get_param( 'link' );

    // validate the request
    if( empty($link)) return new WP_REST_Response( 'Bad Request', 400 );

    // pull the previous click data
    $prev = get_user_meta($user_id, 'link_clicks', true);

    // generate if it doesn't already exist
    if( ! $prev || ! is_array($prev)) $prev = array();

    // make sure the value is numeric
    if( ! is_numeric($prev[$link]) ){
        $prev[$link] = 0;
    }

    // increment based on the click
    $prev[$link]++;

    // update the users metadata
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'link_clicks', $prev, null );

    // return success response
    return new WP_REST_Response( 'OK', 200 );
}
```

To read to clicks back, query for users with click meta data:

```
function get_clicks_by_user() {
    $args  = array (
        'meta_query' => array (
            array (
                'key'     => 'link_clicks',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ),
        ),
    );
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    $clicks_by_user = array ();
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $clicks_by_user[ $user->data->user_login ] = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'link_clicks', true );
    }

    return $clicks_by_user;
}
```

And display the results:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(  get_clicks_by_user() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function user_tracking_script() {
?><script>jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
    var a = jQuery(this)[0];
    if (a.hostname === window.location.hostname) {return true;}
    window.wp.ajax.send('tracking-click', {url: a.hostname})
    return true;
  })
})</script><?php
}
```